# Is it possible to access the different Structure with same members by using Macros or any other functionality at runtime?(Structure updated))

Tags: c, types, macros, structure

In this code contains two structures and their naming is different. Structure member naming is same but type is different. Is there any possibility to change the structure name at run time by using macros or other functionality.

```
typedef struct STag_ABCRegisters
{
    unsigned long aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned long ccc;
    unsigned long dddd;

}RegistersABC;
typedef struct STag_CDERegisters
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned short bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;

}RegistersCDE;

main()
{
    int type = 1;
    if(type == 1)
    {
        RegistersABC->ccc = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        RegistersCDE->ccc = 10;
    }
    /* after some process again checking the type updating structure*/
    type = 2;
    if(type == 1)
    {
        RegistersABC->aaa = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        RegistersCDE->aaa = 10;
    }

}
```

I need the help for following process
In the above code contains complexity of if else condition.
So **is there any possibilities for select the structure at run time??**.

See the below Pseudo code steps for your understanding

```
main()
{

    char type = "ABC";
    Registers//type//->aaa = 10;  // Type of structure name should be  replaced here
}
```

Comment: Yes. Structures are just the way memory is organized on the machine. If both structures were compiled by the same compiler on the same machine (architecture), the memory footprint will be the same and you can simply cast their pointer to one to a pointer of the other.

Comment: If you accept C++ code, you can first define a base class `VirtualRegisters`. Then if `STag_ABCRegisters` and if `STag_CDERegisters`inherits from it, you can choose the right concrete class later. The fields  `aaa` can be present in `VirtualRegisters` to avoid if else constructs or in the derived classes.

Comment: You did that with if statements.

Comment: Why would you define exactly the same thing twice with different names and then struggle with accessing them under one name...?

Comment: @TomDoodler - These structures are going to be used in Embedded systems, While creating structure we will be giving corresponding Hardware address also to that particular structure. For that only this thing is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, structures are just the way memory is organized on the machine.

If both structures were compiled by the same compiler on the same machine (architecture / OS), their memory footprint will be the same and you can simply cast their pointer to one to a pointer of the other.

This, however, is not the best way to go about "inheritance" with C.

At the moment, you can have something like this:

```
struct STag_ABCRegisters
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;

} RegistersABC;

struct STag_CDERegisters
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;

} RegistersCDE;

main()
{
    (struct STag_CDERegisters*) pdata = (struct STag_CDERegisters*)&RegistersABC;
    data->ccc = 10;
    data->aaa = 10;
}
```

It works, but it isn't beautiful.

If you need two of the same, the correct way would be:

```
struct STag_Registers
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;

};
struct STag_Registers RegistersABC, RegistersCDE;

main()
{
    struct STag_Registers * data = &RegistersABC;
    data->ccc = 10;
    data->aaa = 10;
}
```

If you need struct inheritance, then the "trick" is to have the "parent" placed at the head of the struct, so that the memory footprint is aligned.

```
struct STag_Registers
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;

};
struct STag_RegistersExtended
{
    struct STag_Registers parent;
    // ... more types
};
```

This allows a pointer to `struct STag_RegistersExtended` to be cast as a pointer to `struct STag_Registers`, so that functions that accept a pointer to `struct STag_Registers` can also accept a pointer to `struct STag_RegistersExtended`.

Good luck with C.

#### EDIT (answering comment)

If you're writing for an embedded system and you have reserved (fixed) memory addresses for the data, you could go with something such as:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;
} register_s;

#define PTR2REG(p) ((register_s *)(p))
#define REG_A PTR2REG(0x1000))
#define REG_B PTR2REG(0x9000))

inline void perform_work(register_s * reg)
{
   reg->ccc = 10;
   // ...
   reg->aaa = 10;
}

main()
{
   perform_work(REG_A);
   perform_work(REG_B);
   if(REG_A->aaa == 10) // should be true
      printf("work was performed");
}
```

You should note that struct have a memory alignment and packing order. The compiler will add padding to the struct you defined in the question, due to the `long`'s memory alignment requirements. You can [read more about struct packing here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

If your embedded system requires an exact bit / byte match (and is free from padding requirements), you should tell the complier not to add any padding. This is often done using `#pragma pack`

#### EDIT 2

I'm not sure where the `type` in your question is derived from... but if you have a global variable with the address for the struct, you could go with:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;
} register_s;

#define PTR2REG(p) ((register_s *)(p))
#define REG_A PTR2REG(0x1000))
#define REG_B PTR2REG(0x9000))

register_s * active_register = REG_A;

inline void perform_work(void)
{
   active_register->ccc = 10;
   // ... active_register might change
   active_register->aaa = 10;
}

main()
{
   perform_work();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Actually this structures are used for Embedded C code, The address for the structure will be allocating manually based on the embedded Hardware. At the time I hope it might not useful. Consider address for  STag_ABCRegisters = 1000 and STag_CDERegisters = 9000.

Comment: Please update me if you have any other option like changing the structure name using stringization operator(##) (but its not helpful).

Comment: @Gopal, I updated my answer to address your comment. I wish you luck. As a side note, we usually don't thank each other (or we would never stop and the site's database will fill up with thankful comments). Instead, we vote up or accept answers that were helpful.

Comment: @Gopal I reviewed your question again and added an update to my answer.

Comment: Okay @Myst, I will follow and will check with your answer. Also I updated the member type of structures. This is also required now.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*This is from a C++ perspective, you really should be more careful with those language tags if this is not what you want*</sub>

Since C++ does not have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), it's not possible to do what you want at runtime. There are workarounds though.

For example one workaround could be to have a common base-class for the common elements (which in your simple example seems to be all). The you could have an [unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) translating strings to pointers to your structure.

Example:

```
struct CommonBase
{
    unsigned short aaa;
    unsigned long bbb;
    unsigned short ccc;
    unsigned short dddd;
};

struct ABC : CommonBase {};
struct DEF : CommonBase {};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<CommonBase>> items = {
        { "ABC", new ABC },
        { "DEF", new DEF }
    };

    std::cout << "Select item to modify (ABC or DEF): ";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    items[input]->aaa = 12;
}
```

For members that are not common, that are unique for each respective structure, then you need to actually check like you do now and then downcast the pointer to the correct type.

---

For a C solution there is none really, except to manually check like you do now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Any thing possible by using stringizing operator?

Comment: @Gopal The "stringizing" operator `#` and the concatenation operator `##` are part of the preprocessor, and can only be used in macros, and as such are a compile-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic languages like python have buildin metadata table for reflection, so we just build one for help. Now it looks much like a script language.

_Generic need C11 std to work.

some code copied from [How to save the result of typeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42222928/6266963)

```
// some code copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222379/how-to-save-the-result-of-typeof
// gcc -std=c11 typeid_of_test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STRU
{
    int32_t aaa;
    double bbb;
    int ccc;
    char dddd;
}STRU;

typedef struct Metainfo
{
    int     type;
    char*   name;     //or hash
    int  offset;
}Metainfo;

enum {TYPE_UNKNOWN, TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHAR, TYPE_DOUBLE};
#define typeid_of(T)  _Generic((T), int: TYPE_INT, long: TYPE_INT, char: TYPE_CHAR, double: TYPE_DOUBLE, default: 0)

#define META(ST_, M_) {typeid_of((__typeof__(((ST_ *)0)->M_))0), #ST_ "." #M_, offsetof(ST_, M_)}
/*                    {          typeid,                             name,      offset      } */

Metainfo meta[]={
    META(STRU, aaa),
    META(STRU, bbb),
    META(STRU, ccc),
    META(STRU, dddd),
};

int set_by_name(char* member_name, char* value, void* p)
{
    int offset=0, type=0;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(meta)/sizeof(Metainfo); i++)
        if(stricmp(member_name, meta[i].name)==0) 
        {
        offset=meta[i].offset;
        type = meta[i].type;
        }

    switch(type)
    {
        case TYPE_INT:
            *(int*)((char*)p+offset) = atoi(value);
            break;
        case TYPE_CHAR:
            *(char*)((char*)p+offset) = atoi(value);
            break;
        case TYPE_DOUBLE:
            *(double*)((char*)p+offset) = atof(value);
            break;
        default:
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(meta)/sizeof(Metainfo); i++)
        printf("type:%d, name: %s, offset: %d\n", meta[i].type, meta[i].name, meta[i].offset);

    STRU b={0};

    set_by_name("stru.bbb", "3.1415926", &b);
    printf("stru.bbb == %f", b.bbb);

    return 0;
}
```