# How to save the result of typeof?

Tags: c, c99, typeof

I am a new programmer that is mostly using Code::Blocks for C**99**.
I recently found out about the `typeof()` because it was hidden as __typeof __()
and I wanted to know if you can save a type as a result of typeof. something like:

```
type a = __typeof__(?);
```

Or

```
#define typeof __typeof__
type a = typeof(?);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There's no `typeof` operator in standard C. You have to read the documentation for the *compiler* (not the Code::Blocks IDE) to find out more information. Also, *don't* do what you want to do, it's in 99.99% of all cases not something you should do. Perhaps if you explain *why* you want to do it, what the *actual problem* is that you want to solve, then we can help you with that instead.

Comment: If `var` has type `int` then `typeof(var)` is `int`. Can you say `type a = int;` or any similar thing? What would it mean? Why would you need something like that?

Comment: Assuming you want to do something comparable to writing `Class c = "foo".getClass();` in Java: Forget it, it doesn't work like that in C. There is no type information available during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid `typeof` or `__typeof __()` since they aren't standard C. The latest C version (C11) has support for this through the `_Generic` keyword which works in the same manner.

There is no "type type" in C but you can easily make one yourself:

```
typedef enum
{
  TYPE_INT,
  TYPE_FLOAT,
  TYPE_CHAR
} type_t;

#define get_typeof(x)   \
  _Generic((x),         \
    int:   TYPE_INT,    \
    float: TYPE_FLOAT,  \
    char:  TYPE_CHAR );

...

float f;
type_t type = get_typeof(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use `typeof` like `t = (typeof(x) == int) ? a : b;` nor `int t = typeof(x);` .

If you are under C11, `_Generic` can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {TYPE_UNKNOWN, TYPE_INT, TYPE_CHAR, TYPE_DOUBLE};

#define type_of(T) _Generic((T), int: TYPE_INT, char: TYPE_CHAR, double: TYPE_DOUBLE, default: 0)

int main(void)
{
    double a = 5.;
    int t = type_of(a);

    switch (t) {
        case TYPE_INT:
            puts("a is int");
            break;
        case TYPE_CHAR:
            puts("a is char");
            break;
        case TYPE_DOUBLE:
            puts("a is double");
            break;
        default:
            puts("a is unknown");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! i changed my compiler to c11 and used the '_Generic'.